# Dependent Picklist issues

Tags: dependent-picklist

**Background**

I have one controlling field Opportunity Stage. I have two custom picklist fields. I placed the custom fields within the Opportunity Path under the stages.

If the Opportunity Stage = 'Negotiation', they are prompted to select a value from custom picklist field 1. If they select the next Opportunity Stage = 'Closed Won', they are prompted to select a value from Custom Picklist 2.

There is no problem making them dependent to Stage picklist field value. When the prompt page pops up, only one of them is selectable according to what opp stage is selected - obviously.

However, when I select a value for Custom Picklist 2, it clears whatever I selected for Custom Picklist 1. What can I do here? I want to make sure my selection in the Negotiation stage stays when I select my next choice at the Closed stage. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Attaching screenshots with the error message or unexpected outcome will go a long way otherwise none of us understands what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to update the dependencies settings section to fix this issue

1. Stage - Custom Pick list 1 values dependencies
2. Stage - Custom pick list 2 values dependencies

As per your statement, Let me assume,

Stage - Custom Pick list 1 values dependencies settings available as below,

> Stage Value : Negotiation
>
> Custom Pick list 1 value : A

Stage - Custom Pick list 2 values dependencies settings available as below,

> Stage Value : Closed Won
>
> Custom Pick list 2 value : B

So if you select Stage as "Negotiation" and Custom Pick list 1 value is "A" in your 1st scenario. **And When you change the stage into "Closed won", System automatically clear the values from Custom Pick list 1 field. Because you're Custom Pick list 1 doesn't have any dependency value for Stage "Closed Won"**.

So if you need to keep Custom piclist 1 value on "Closed Won" stage also means, You need to enable the value "A" (our assume value) for stage "Closed Won" also as follows,

Stage - Custom Pick list 1 values dependencies settings available as follow combination,

```
Stage Value : Negotiation

Custom Pick list 1 value : A

Stage Value : Closed Won

Custom Pick list 1 value : A
```

Then if you change the Opportunity stage "Negotiation" to "closed Won" means, system doesn't clear any value and it's available in opportunity record as follows,

> Stage : Closed Won
>
> Custom Pick list 1 value : A
>
> Custom Pick list 2 value : B

Please let me know if it helps.